# Prototype.js unescapeHTML For All Elements In Objects

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have an object that has lots of strings in it.  What I am looking to do is use prototypes unescapeHTML on each string within the object.

```
var messageStrings = {
    string1: "Some String 1",
    string2: "Some String 2",
    string3: "Some String 3"
}
```

Something like an each command that resets the value.  Can't quite figure out how to do it.  Can someone lend me a hand in how I would cycle through an object like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like so:

```
for(var key in messageStrings) {
    messageStrings[key].unescapeHTML()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For loop works great, but for some reason the unescapeHTML has no effect. Any idea why?  Using 1.6.1 of Prototype and getting no js errors. One string in particular is "Mettre &agrave; jour" that just stays that way.  I tried messageStrings[key] = messageStrings[key].unescapeHTML() as well.

Comment: Nevermind, seems as though it doesn't support all html entities.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid writing yet another loop:

```
messageStrings.invoke('unescapeHTML');
```